# Normalizer of a quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $A, B$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$ with $B\unlhd A$.

In a paper I have read, they say that the normalizer of $A/B$ in $H$ is $N_H(A/B) = N_H(A) \cap N_H(B)$. I am having a difficulty showing this as I am not sure what an element looks like in $N_H(A/B)$

My second question is what can we say about the induced automorphisms of $A/B$ using $N_H(A/B)$

Comment: What's the definition of $N_H(A/B)$?

Comment: They just say that it is the normalizer of $A/B$ in $H$. Do you think it is defined as $N_H(A/B) = N_H(A) \cap N_H(B)$? This makes more sense

Comment: Yes, if I was asked to define it I would just do it like that! An element $g \in N_H(A/B)$ induces an automorphisms of $A/B$ by conjugation, by $aB \mapsto gag^{-1}B$ for $a \in A$. I don't think you can say much more in general. You could also define $C_H(A/B)$ as those $g \in N_H(A/B)$ that map to the identity automorphism. That is $g \in C_H(A/B) \Leftrightarrow gag^{-1} \in aB$ for all $a \in A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H, A$  any  subgroups of $G$, the normalizer of $A$ relatively to $H$ is the intersection of $H$ with the normalizer of $A$ in $G$, that  is  $h \in H$ such that
$hAh ^ {-1} = A$. If $B$ is a subgroup normal in $A$, the normalizer of the quotient group  $A/B$  relatively  to $H$ is  the set of elements $h$ of $H$ that define automorphism passing  at the quotient ie element $h$  such that the morphism composit $p_B \gamma_h$ factorises via $P_B$ where  $p_B$ is the canonical projection and $\gamma_h$ the automorphism of conjugation by $h$ of $G$, ie  such  element $h$ is in the normalizer of $B$ relatively to $H$. Thus, it has the desired equality.